# JQUery change value of variable on button click with return

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, variables

i am trying to make a questionaire that once completed by the user will give an response dependent on their answer. i decided to do this via making variables for each answer which get +1 dependending on their click. and at the end display the variable with the highest value. seems simple enough but for some reason variables not responding to changes on clicks

heres my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container contentContainer text-center" id="top-Container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


    <div id="questions"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <div id="buts"> 

    <input id="a1" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="a">
    <input id="b1" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="b">
    </div>

    <div id="buts2">

    <input id="a2" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="do you prefer a ">
    <input id="b2" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="b">
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

        var ansa        ="this is answera";
        var ansb    ="this is answerb";

        //questions//
        var Q1 = "do you prefer answerb ?"; 
        var Q2 = "do you prefer answera?";


        $("#questions").html(Q1);



                for (var i=0; i<15; i++) {
            $("#buts"+[i]).hide();
        }



                //need more diagnosises//
        var answera=0;
        var answerb=0;


        $("#a1").click(function(){

            answera+=1;
            $("#questions").html(Q2);
            $("#buts").hide();
            $("#buts2").fadeIn();

        });
        $("#b1").click(function(){
            answera+=1;
            $("#questions").html(Q2);
            $("#buts").hide();
            $("#buts2").fadeIn();
        });

        //Is it affected by hot or cold//
        $("#a2").click(function(){
            answerb+=1;
            answera+=1;
            $("#questions").html(Q3);
            $("#buts2").hide();

        });
        $("#b2").click(function(){
            answerb+=1;

            $("#questions").html(Q3);
            $("#buts2").hide();

        });

    console.log(answera);
    console.log(answerb);

    if (answera>answerb) {
        $("#answers").html(ansa);
        }else {
        $("#answers").html(ansb);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#answers` should be changed to `#answer`, because the `id` of `div` that you have assigned, is `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#questions").html(Q3);
```

Q3 is not defined